# $\text{colim}(F\circ i)=\text{colim}(F)$

Tags: category-theory

Let $\Lambda$ be a filtered category, $\Gamma$ (just) a category and $\Lambda \xrightarrow{i} \Gamma$ a cofinal functor (for all $\gamma \in \Gamma$ exists $\gamma \rightarrow i(\lambda)$ with $\lambda \in \Lambda$). Then, for all functor $\Gamma \xrightarrow{F} \mathcal{X}$, if $\text{colim}(F\circ i)$ exists we have that $\text{colim}(F)$ also exists and $\text{colim}(F\circ i)=\text{colim}(F)$.

I can't prove the statement with these hypothesis. But I can if $\Gamma$ is also filtered and $i$ is full. Are these extra hypothesis necesary o is there a way to solve the problem as it is?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your definition of cofinal is wrong, or your hypotheses are wrong. It is also very strange to ask about colimits _in_ a filtered category.

Comment: What is even weirder is that you ask for colimits inside the category $\Lambda$, so $F \circ i$ is a functor $\Lambda \to \Lambda$... My guess is that you want $F$ to have arbitrary codomain. Then, with a fixed definition of cofinal, this is true.

Comment: Sorry, I edited it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing one condition in the definition of a cofinal functor. We also need that for any $f: \gamma \to i(\lambda)$ and $f': \gamma \to i(\lambda')$ there are $g: \lambda \to \mu$ and $g': \lambda' \to \mu$ in $\Lambda$ such that $i(g)f = i(g') f'$.

Let $F: \Gamma \to \mathcal{X}$ be any functor. The key point is that there is a bijective correspondence between cocones on $F$ and cocones on $Fi$. In fact, a neat way of making this precise is saying the the categories of cocones on $F$ and $Fi$ are equivalent.

One direction for this is easy. Let $(f_\gamma: F(\gamma) \to X)_{\gamma \in \Gamma}$ be a cocone for $F$. Then $(f_{i(\lambda)}: Fi(\lambda) \to X)_{\lambda \in \Lambda}$ is a cocone for $Fi$. So we are just restricting to the image of $i$.

The other direction is more involved. It might be helpful to draw diagrams to keep track of what is happening. Suppose we are given a cocone $(f_\lambda: Fi(\lambda) \to X)_{\lambda \in \Lambda}$ for $Fi$. For every $\gamma \in \Gamma$ choose a $\lambda_\gamma \in \Lambda$ together with an arrow $c_\gamma: \gamma \to i(\lambda_\gamma)$. We then define $g_\gamma = f_{\lambda_\gamma} F(c_\gamma): F(\gamma) \to X$. We need to check that $(g_\gamma: F(\gamma) \to X)_{\gamma \in \Gamma}$ forms a cocone. So let $h: \gamma \to \gamma'$ be any arrow. Then we have arrows $c_\gamma: \gamma \to i(\lambda_\gamma)$ and $c_{\gamma'}h: \gamma \to i(\lambda_{\gamma'})$. By the condition mentioned at the beginning there are $t: \lambda_\gamma \to \mu$ and $t': \lambda_{\gamma'} \to \mu$ for some $\mu$ such that $i(t) c_\gamma = i(t') c_{\gamma'} h$. So we indeed have
$$
g_\gamma =
f_{\lambda_\gamma} F(c_\gamma) =
f_\mu F(i(t) c_\gamma) =
f_\mu F(i(t') c_{\gamma'} h) = 
f_{\lambda_{\gamma'}} F(c_{\gamma'} h) =
g_{\gamma'} F(h).
$$
The first and last equality are definitions, the second and fourth equalities are due to $(f_\lambda: Fi(\lambda) \to X)_{\lambda \in \Lambda}$ being a cocone and the third equality is by choice of $t$ and $t'$.

Your main question now easily follows. This is direct from the neat description that the categories of cocones are equivalent. If you are uncomfortable with that kind of description then checking the details is not hard. A colimiting cocone $(f_\lambda: Fi(\lambda) \to X)_{\lambda \in \Lambda}$ on $Fi$ yields a cocone $(g_\gamma: F(\gamma) \to X)_{\gamma \in \Gamma}$ on $F$. For any other cocone $(g_\gamma': F(\gamma) \to X')_{\gamma \in \Gamma}$ on $F$ we get a cocone $(g_{i(\lambda)}': Fi(\lambda) \to X')_{\lambda \in \Lambda}$ on $Fi$ and thus a universal arrow $u: X \to X'$ because $(f_\lambda: Fi(\lambda) \to X)_{\lambda \in \Lambda}$ is colimiting. It is an easy check that this $u$ is also the universal arrow for $(g_\gamma: F(\gamma) \to X)_{\gamma \in \Gamma}$ and $(g_\gamma': F(\gamma) \to X')_{\gamma \in \Gamma}$.

---

Note that we did not need that $\Lambda$ is filtered.